# How to deal with "housekeeping" fields in record types?

Tags: haskell, yesod, persistent

Every table in my DB needs to have a `created_at` and `updated_at` field for general hygiene and housekeeping. This leads to Persistent models which look like this:

```
User
  email String Maybe
  name String Maybe
  tgramUserId TgramUserId Maybe
  createdAt UTCTime
  updatedAt UTCTime
  deriving Show
```

Now, I have a bunch of APIs for creating users, based on different business cases. For example:

- createUserFromWebForm
- createUserFromTelegram
- createUserFromOAuth

I'd like the type-signatures of each of these APIs to be:

```
createUserFromX :: User -> SqlPersistM (Entity User)
```

However, this would mean that every call-site for `createUserFromX` will need to call `getCurrentTime` and set the `createdAt` and `updatedAt` house-keeping fields. What's the way to localize this complexity within these APIs itself?

One unclean (IMO) solution is to change the signature to:

```
createUserFromTelegram :: Maybe TgramUserId -> SqlPersistM (Entity User)
```

... but that defeats the purpose of using record-types in the first place (In this particular example, you can probably argue in-favour of this approach, but what if the record-type had 10 fields)?

Comment: as all your functions deal with `User` it should be simple to refactor out a function like `updateTimes :: User -> IO User` and just use this - if you want to do this for more than `User` then you probably want to introduce some type-class for this

Answer (score 3):

> However, this would mean that every call-site for createUserFromX will need to call getCurrentTime and set the createdAt and updatedAt house-keeping fields.

It's not true. The definition of `SqlPersistM` is:

```
type SqlPersistM = SqlPersistT (NoLoggingT (ResourceT IO))
type SqlPersistT = ReaderT SqlBackend
```

So `SqlPersistM` has an instance of MonadIO, you can perform any IO action inside your `createUserFromX` by `liftIO your_io_action`:

```
createUserFromX :: User -> SqlPersistM (Entity User)
createUserFromX user = do
    utctime <- liftIO getCurrentTime
    let user' = user { createdAt = utctime, updatedAt = utctime }
    -- your codes
```